# Java Files.copy throws FileNotFoundException with Symbolic Links

Tags: java, file, nio

I have code this code
`Files.copy(source, destination, options);` which should copy any file from source to destination. However, when it encounters a symbolic link. I get `FileNotFoundException`

What is going on? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

The problem I had was that while copying files, it was attempting to follow the symlink file and copy that as well, however, it didn't find the original file. That is why it is throwing a `FileNotFoundException`.

As a fix I used this:
`LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS` as an option and it worked fine.

Comment: Good usage of the Self-Answer format on SO. It's underutilized and you used it properly.